# How to define Mccs/Clingo as a OPAM solver instead of aspcud

Tags: ocaml, opam

I am a newbie using OPAM version 4.05.0, I got some issues while installing depext package with `apscud` as a solver.

In the OPAM config file `~/.opam/config`, I added this a line as the solver was unspecified `solver: Mccs`

I am pretty sure that I am doing it wrong, because it is trying to install depext package since 45 minutes ago.

How to define `Mccs/Clingo` as a solver ?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no 4.05.0 version of opam. I think you are talking about the version of OCaml.

Comment: My bad, indeed that's OCaml version, and the OPAM's one is 2.0.3

Answer (score 3):

To set an external solver to opam, we first need to install it.
for my part, the mccs solver is located in `/bin/mccs`

Firstable, we set the global variable `$OPAMEXTERNALSOLVER` in `~/.opam/default/.opam-switch/environment` as follow: 
`OPAMEXTERNALSOLVER = /bin/mccs`

Secondly, we set the solver parameter in opam's config file `~/.opam/config` as follow: `solver: mccs`

The final part consist to update opam by launching the command `eval $(opam env)`

We can check the modifications by launching the commands:
`opam config env`
`opam config report`

Credits: https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/External_solvers.html

It worked for me, yeey ^^